# dbt incremental model in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, dbt

From this model, and according to my understanding of the documentation of dbt:

**EDIT: (removed the DISTINCT in the statement as it was unnecessary)**

**Test.sql**

```
{{ config(
        as_columnstore = false,
        schema='staging',
        materialized='incremental', 
        unique_key='id',
        incremental_strategy='merge',
        merge_update_columns = ['name', 'updated_at'])
    }}

SELECT  I.id, 
        I.name, 
        MAX(I.extraction_date) created_at,
        MAX(I.extraction_date) updated_at
  FROM staging.test_data_raw I 
 WHERE I.id IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY I.id, I.name
```

I expected that, if a record with a matching **Id** already existed, in the table then the **name** and the **updated_at** would change but the **created_at** would remain as it was

But, after running it several times, the created_at always changes. So my guess is that dbt is not performing a merge operation but a delete/insert.

I am running dbt with the SQL Server connector.

Is it possible that this connector does not implement the merge strategy?
Or am I doing something wrong here? And if so, is there any way to solve this?

Comment: A `DISTINCT` with a `GROUP BY` is always a sign of a flaw in your query. A `GROUP BY` already causes your data to be returned in *distinct* sets, so if you are getting duplicates, it likely means your `GROUP BY` is wrong. Otherwise the `DISTINCT` is redundant and unneeded overhead. I would suggest the latter here.

Comment: Yes, you're right the DISTINCT is an error, I've made a simple test and forgot to remove it... I am editing the OP to remove this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sitting here and wondering about the same thing (but with Azure DW). No positive response in 15 days, so I guess the answer must be that the incremental strategy "merge" has not yet been implemented in the dbt-sqlserver adapter. Go to https://github.com/dbt-msft/dbt-sqlserver/discussions/categories/ideas and suggest this feature!

Comment: Yes, you're right, I checked the /target folders and the translation from the dbt models to SQL Server syntax is basically DELETE/INSERT. So I went with a Pre_Hook/Post_Hook approach to make the desired MERGE. Not the best solution, that's for sure. But, at least, does what I need